# How can I NOT save an image in PIL?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I have seen only way to save all the images in PIL but ***i dont want to save them*** all. I'm making a discord bot to send the meme with the user profile picture in space. Using Visual Studio Code
Any way i just save a pile of useless images in my laptop?

```
#spongebob burning meme
@client.command(name= "spongebob_burn")
async def spongebob_burn(content, user: discord.member = None):
    if user is None:
        user = content.author
    
    spongebob_burn = Image.open("memes/Spongebobburn.jpeg")
    asset= user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data= BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)

    pfp = pfp.resize((74,74))
    spongebob_burn.paste(pfp, (22,45))
    spongebob_burn.save('sbb_new.jpeg')

    await content.send(file= discord.File("sbb_new.jpeg"))
```

i tried removing the save line as that was my first instinct but then i overthought how and what it will send

so i tried straight away the show command and and other ways to do which my brain could handle

Comment: Have you tried deleting the line `spongebob_burn.save('sbb_new.jpeg')` ?

Comment: then do i just change
await content.send(file= discord.File("sbb_new.jpeg"))
to await content.send(file= discord.File("memes/Spongebobburn.jpeg"))```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what part of the code do you think is responsible for saving the image? (Hint: which line of your code has the word `save` in it?) What do you think will happen if you try not including that code? What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Replace the `save()` command with one that writes to another `BytesIO` (like where you read it) and then `getbuffer()` on that BytesIO and send the result instead of a file.

Comment: Anyway, if you are just grabbing random pieces of code and don't understand them, you should *not be trying to write a project at this level*. Learn the fundamentals first. If you have a more sophisticated question (for example, there is something *specific* that you want to do with the image data *instead of* saving it) then you should a) do the [expected minimum research for your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) (see [ask]), and then ask that question if you still have one.

Comment: i am right now reading the whole PIL's database to know more and how to do yet my brain cells are not working right now

Comment: i tried removing the save line as that was my first instinct but then i overthought how and what it will send
so i tried straight away the ```show()``` command and and other ways to do which my brain could handle 

i am now trying to write another BytesIO command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was already answered in the comments by **Mark Setchell**, but it seems that you cannot really wrap your head around it so I'll write an answer.

You can save the image to an output buffer and then simply send the buffer instead.

```py
from io import BytesIO

@client.command(name= "spongebob_burn")
async def spongebob_burn(content, user: discord.member = None):
    if user is None:
        user = content.author
    
    spongebob_burn = Image.open("memes/Spongebobburn.jpeg")
    asset = user.avatar_url_as(size=128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)

    output_buffer = BytesIO()
    pfp = pfp.resize((74,74))
    spongebob_burn.paste(pfp, (22,45))
    spongebob_burn.save(output_buffer, "jpeg")

    await content.send(file=discord.File(fp=output_buffer, filename="sbb_new.jpeg"))
```

Comment: thank you so much i just wasnt using my brain that day T-T